# Why does MySQL inserts blank data in not null fields

Tags: mysql, insert

I just wanted to know if somebody could explain this.

I was just testing my code and didn't check for empty input fields (I know I have to, but just testing).. In my database table, all the fields are NOT NULL, and I was expecting a exception because I wasn't inserting anything.. But it turns out that MySQL inserts all with blank values, also, from MySQL workbench is the same thing..

Is there a way to prevent this? (From a MySQL perspective)

Comment: Are there default values defined on your schema?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that MySQL not null property just indicates that the field will never be null, not that it won't be empty. Handling emptiness should be done on the application end.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior, although atypical, is quite well [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

> Inserting NULL into a column that has been declared NOT NULL. For
>   multiple-row `INSERT` statements or `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statements,
>   the column is set to the implicit default value for the column data
>   type. This is 0 for numeric types, the empty string ('') for string
>   types, and the “zero” value for date and time types. `INSERT INTO ...
>   SELECT` statements are handled the same way as multiple-row inserts
>   because the server does not examine the result set from the SELECT to
>   see whether it returns a single row. (For a single-row `INSERT`, no
>   warning occurs when NULL is inserted into a NOT NULL column. Instead,
>   the statement fails with an error.)

So, if you want to get an error, use `VALUES()` with a single row.  Alternatively, define a trigger that does the check.

Why does MySQL work this way?  I don't know, to differentiate itself from other databases and prevent ANSI-compatibility?  More seriously, I assume that this a question of efficiency, and related to the fact that MySQL does not implement `check` constraints.  The `NOT NULL` declaration is just an example of a check constraint, and these are not supported.